# Prevent insert value depending on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-insert

Suppose I have a table called `MANT` like this

```
date           state
2020-01-24  |   0
2020-01-27  |   1
```

And I have another table called `PREC` like this

```
value    date 
0.00  | 2020-05-18  
0.00  | 2020-05-19  
0.00  | 2020-05-20
```

If I try and insert these values in `PREC`

```
insert into PREC VALUES (4,'2020-01-25')
```

I want that this to be impossible, since in table `MANT`, state = 0 in a oldest date that the date inserted in `PREC`

But if I insert for example:

```
insert into PREC VALUES (4,'2020-01-29')
```

That would already be allowed.

Anyone have some suggestion to do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `insert ... select` syntax and a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
insert into prec(value, date)
select v.*
from (values (4,'2020-01-25')) v(value, date)
where (select top (1) m.date from mant m where m.date <= v.date order by m.date desc) = 1
```

You can also do this with aggregation:

```
insert into prec(value, date)
select v.*
from (values (4,'2020-01-25')) v(value, date)
where (select max(m.date) from mant m where m.date <= v.date) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to allow direct INSERT.You can control it through stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PREC_Insert 
@value INT
,@DateValue DATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @maxDate DATE = (
            SELECT max(DATE)
            FROM PREC
            )
    DECLARE @errorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)

    IF @Datevalue > @maxDate
    BEGIN
        SET @errorMessage = 'You cannot insert date value older than ' + CAST(@maxDate AS VARCHAR(12) 
        throw 51000, @errorMessage, 1;
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        -- Do the insert
    END 

END
```

If you want to allow direct insert, you can handle it using AFTER INSERT trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for Insert triggers throwing exceptions. An example would be below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER person_id_trigg
AFTER INSERT
    ON person
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF( NOT EXISTS(select max(m.date) from mant m where m.date <= v.date AND state = 1) )
        THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 
                         'The MANT date is invalid for PREC' );
        END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I think the question is for SQL Server RDBMS. Your answer might be different RDBMS